# Can't install json with gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, macos, rubygems

I have tried following command in terminal (OSX 10.6.6) and end up with an error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
sudo gem install json 

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/re.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:834:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:833:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:17:in `'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.5.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to install XCode. It is available on the AppStore

If XCode is installed and you are still getting this error, maybe you should try using rvm

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have XCode installed already (the one came with snow leopard osx installation CD).

Comment: did you install ruby 1.9.1 using macports?

Comment: No, I used rvm. Can it be a problem?

Comment: maybe u need readline or something rvm package install readline
rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-readline-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr

Comment: u may also want to do a fresh install of your ruby and gems after that

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because the json gem includes C/C++ extensions that need to be compiled on your machine before they can run.

Just installing XCode won't fix it, you need to specifically install the XCode Command Line Tools. It's a compiler/linker toolchain including C/C++ compilers, make, etc.

There's an option to install them within a menu inside the XCode GUI, see this thread for details:

[Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-command-line-tools)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the necessary tools installed by running:

```
> xcode-select --install
```